# fb:like is appearing outside td in Safari

Tags: facebook, html-table, safari, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I am using Facebook Like Button on my page inside table cell

```
<table style="position:relative;">
  <tr style="position:relative;">
    <td>
      <table  cellpadding='0' style='border:solid 1px black;width:100%;'>
        <tr align='left'>
          <td align='left'>
            <fb:like send="false" layout="standard" width="350"
                     style="height:22px;" show_faces="false"
                     action="like" colorscheme="light"
            ></fb:like>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">SOME TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In IE 9 and Google Chrome it is appearing correctly inside the black border set to the table.

[image: screenshot-correct]

But in Safari it is appearing outside the `td`.

[image: screenshot-wrong]

Why is this happening? I've tried to set Like Button style `position` to `relative` but same thing. Is there anything different in CSS for Safari?

Comment: Can you provide a sample which breaks in Safari on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or provide a URL where the problem can be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of other styling you have on page. You need to fix the styling that wasn't provided in your sample code.

Your code alone is working as expected in Safari (on Mac),  so isolating the problem shouldn't be hard. See live example: [before formatting](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpju7/), [after formatting](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpju7/1/)

Comment: You are right. The problem is from this code <html dir="rtl" Any ideas what to do?